# Can I draw a step by step my backtracking using Processing?

Tags: processing, backtracking

I want to write a backtracking -8 Queens- visualization code using processing.

So I tried to use `noLoop()` inside `setup()` and call `redraw()` followed by a `delay(100)` in each update step but it didn't work.

Here are my functions.

```
int cellH = 38, cellW = 38, n = 8;
PImage img;
boolean [][] grid;
boolean [] visC, visMD, visSD;
boolean firstTime = true;

void drawQueen(int r, int c){
  image(img, c*cellW, r*cellH, cellW, cellH);
}

void drawGrid(){
  background(255);
  for(int r = 0 ; r < n ; ++r){
    for(int c = 0 ; c < n ; ++c){
     if((r&1) != (c&1)) fill(0);
     else  fill(255);
     rect(c*cellW, r*cellH, (c+1)*cellW, (r+1)*cellH);
   }
  }
}

void updateQueens(){
  for(int r = 0 ; r < n ; ++r)
    for(int c = 0 ; c < n ; ++c)
      if(grid[r][c] == true)
        drawQueen(r, c);
}
boolean backTrack(int r){
 if(r == n)  return true;
 else{
   for(int c = 0 ; c < n ; ++c){
     if(!visC[c] && !visMD[n+r-c] && !visSD[r+c]){
       //Do
       grid[r][c] = visC[c] = visMD[n+r-c] = visSD[r+c] = true;
       redraw();
       delay(100);
       //Recurse
       if(backTrack(r+1))  return true;
       //Undo
       grid[r][c] = visC[c] = visMD[n+r-c] = visSD[r+c] = false;
     }
   }
 }
 return false;
}

void setup(){
  size(280, 280);
  cellH = 280/n;
  cellW = 280/n;

  grid = new boolean[n][n];
  visC = new boolean[n];
  visMD = new boolean[2*n];
  visSD = new boolean[2*n];

  noLoop();
  img = loadImage("queen.png");
  backTrack(0);
}

void draw(){
  drawGrid();
  updateQueens();
}
```

When I run the sketch only the final state appears.

Are there any other Idea to do so?

Comment: When you add `println("Redrawing");` before `redraw();`, is it printed a bunch of times?

Comment: Could you show us your drawGrid function please?

Comment: @J.D. Yes, it prints.

Comment: @DWuest added the full code.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Are there any trick to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve it using a `Thread` and it gave me an excellent output, so here's my code:

```
int cellH = 38, cellW = 38, n = 8;
PImage img;
boolean [][] grid;
boolean [] visC, visMD, visSD;
boolean firstTime = true;

Thread thread;

void setup(){
  size(560, 560);
  cellH = 560/n;
  cellW = 560/n;

  grid = new boolean[n][n];
  visC = new boolean[n];
  visMD = new boolean[2*n];
  visSD = new boolean[2*n];
  img = loadImage("queen.png");
  thread = new Thread(new MyThread());

  thread.start();
}

void draw(){
  if(thread.isAlive())
    drawGrid();
  else{
    noLoop();
    endRecord();
    return;
  }
}

void drawGrid(){
  background(255);
  for(int r = 0 ; r < n ; ++r){
   for(int c = 0 ; c < n ; ++c){
     if((r&1) != (c&1)) fill(0);
     else  fill(255);
     rect(c*cellW, r*cellH, (c+1)*cellW, (r+1)*cellH);
     if(grid[r][c] == true)
       image(img, c*cellW, r*cellH, cellW, cellH);
   }
  }
}

boolean backTrack(int r){
  if(r == n)  return true;
  else{
    for(int c = 0 ; c < n ; ++c){
      if(!visC[c] && !visMD[n+r-c] && !visSD[r+c]){
        //Do
        grid[r][c] = visC[c] = visMD[n+r-c] = visSD[r+c] = true;

        try{
          Thread.sleep(200);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}  

        //Recurse
        if(backTrack(r+1))  return true;
        //Undo
        grid[r][c] = visC[c] = visMD[n+r-c] = visSD[r+c] = false;

        try{
          Thread.sleep(200);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

class MyThread implements Runnable{    
  public void run(){    
    backTrack(0);    
  }
}
```

And here's the output:

[image: The output of the sketch]

Comment: Very nice approach. It generalizes well, and can be used to visualize almost any algorithm with very few edits.

Answer (score 3):

The way it is with processing, is that you simulate loops by turning the `draw` function to the body of that loop and do all the initialization in `setup` function.

To simulate a recursion, you can turn it into a loop then do the above, usually this can be made using a stack and you basically replace the system's stack with yours; I have done some reading (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration) for some thoughts) and I found it would be very easy to turn the recursion into loop with a stack if the recursive call is at the end of the function's body.

Now the  problem here, is that you have some code **after** the recursive call that should be executed after the call returns, but looking into it, it's just *undoing* changes made to global variables, we can overcome that if we consider those variables as a part of the state (not very efficient and won't scale well, but in your case it will do) so the *undo* part won't be necessary and the recursive call will be the last thing in the function's body (let's leave the inner for-loop for now).

So to do that I defined a class called `State` and it is as follows ..

```
    class State {
      private final int SIZE = 8;
      private boolean grid[][], visC[], visR[], visMD[], visSD[];

      int r, c;

      State() {
        visC = new boolean[SIZE];
        visR = new boolean[SIZE];
        visMD = new boolean[2*SIZE];
        visSD = new boolean[2*SIZE];
        grid = new boolean[SIZE][SIZE];
      }

      State(State other) {
        this();
        cpyArr(other.visMD, this.visMD);
        cpyArr(other.visSD, this.visSD);
        cpyArr(other.visC, this.visC);
        cpyArr(other.visR, this.visR);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < other.grid.length ; ++i)
          for (int j = 0 ; j < other.grid[i].length ; ++j)
            this.grid[i][j] = other.grid[i][j];

        this.r = other.r;
        this.c = other.c;
      }

      void cpyArr(boolean from[], boolean to[]) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < from.length ; ++i) to[i] = from[i];
      }

      boolean isValid(int r, int c) {
        return (r < SIZE && c < SIZE && !visR[r] && !visC[c] && !visMD[SIZE + r - c] && !visSD[r + c]);
      }

      // actually update this sate with r and c
      void affect() {
        grid[r][c] = visC[c] = visMD[SIZE + r - c] = visSD[r + c] = true;
      }

      PVector[] getPositions() {
        ArrayList<PVector> ret = new ArrayList<PVector>();
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
          for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
            if (grid[i][j]) ret.add(new PVector(j, i));
        return ret.toArray(new PVector[0]);
      }
    }
```

it contains all that would be needed to represent the state of that recursion, now the code would look something like ..

```
stack.push(initialState);
while(stack.size() != 0) {
    State currentState = stack.pop();
    // do stuff ...
    stack.push(nextState);
}
```

We can consider the body of `draw` function as the body of that while loop and use `noLoop()` to stop it when the stack is empty, so the final code would be something like ..

```
import java.util.Stack;

final int GRID_SIZE = 8;
float cellH, cellW;
PImage img;

Stack<State> stack;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  frameRate(5);

  cellH = (float) height / GRID_SIZE;
  cellW = (float) width / GRID_SIZE;

  img = loadImage("queen.png");

  stack = new Stack<State>();
  State state = new State();
  state.r = -1;
  state.c = -1;
  stack.push(state);

  noLoop();

}

void draw() {
  // stop if the stack is empty
  if (stack.size() == 0) {
    noLoop();
    return;
  }

  State current = stack.pop();
  drawGrid(current);

  // stop when a solution is found
  if (current.r == GRID_SIZE - 1) {
    noLoop();
    return;
  }

  for (int c = GRID_SIZE - 1; c >= 0; --c) {
    State next = new State(current);

    if (!next.isValid(current.r+1, c)) continue;
    next.c = c;
    next.r = current.r + 1;
    next.affect();

    stack.push(next);
  }

}

void drawGrid(State state) {
  float cellH = height / GRID_SIZE;
  float cellW = width / GRID_SIZE;

  background(255);
  for (int r = 0; r < GRID_SIZE; ++r) {
    for (int c = 0; c < GRID_SIZE; ++c) {
      if ((r&1) != (c&1)) fill(0);
      else  fill(255);
      rect(c*cellW, r*cellH, (c+1)*cellW, (r+1)*cellH);
    }
  }

  PVector pos[] = state.getPositions();
  for (PVector vec : pos) {
    image(img, vec.x * cellW + cellW * 0.1, vec.y * cellH + cellH * 0.1, cellW * 0.8, cellH * 0.8);
  }
}

// to resume the search after a solution is found
void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') loop();
}
```

Notice that *inner for-loop* part that we left for later, it's reversed so the first state to be executed is the same as the first state that the backtracking would have explored.

Now putting some nice image for the *queen.png* resource in data file, the result is very nice ...

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://processing.org/reference/redraw_.html):

> In structuring a program, it only makes sense to call redraw() within 
>   events such as mousePressed(). This is because redraw() does not run 
>   draw() immediately (it only sets a flag that indicates an update is 
>   needed).

Redraw doesn't cause the screen to drawn. Its sets a flag that draw() needs to be called, which happens at the end of the loop. A solution is to rename `draw()` to `drawScreen()` and call that instead of `redraw()`.

Comment: I doesn't work, the documentation says:
_All Processing programs update the screen at the end of draw(), never earlier._

Comment: if you add `println("Calling draw");` above `redraw()` and  `println("Drawing");` to `draw()` you'll see what I mean. 'Calling draw' is printed multiple times, at the end 'Drawing' is printed - once. Now rename `redraw()`  to `draw()` -(turning it into a direct function call) The print statements will alternate, meaning every update is drawn.

Comment: Yes, the word is printed but, without updating the scene.